# Where to look for app binary and .dsym file in corona Project

Tags: ios, binaryfiles, coronasdk, dsym

I am creating an app in corona SDK.But unfortunately my app crashes sometimes on my iPad and through console I found out that crash report has been built and saved. I look at this crash report in xcode but it didn't symbolicate it properly. I searched and found out that I require application binary and .dsym file for xcode to symbolicate it completely. Now when I build a corona project, it results into an `application file` and from its contents, I am unable to find any `.dsym` or `binary file`. I need these files to read the crash report and find out the actual bug in app.